# Decorator does not work properly with yield command

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, yield, nonetype

Since I use the same try-catch block very often, I've decided to create a decorator which does it automatically.

```
def tryexc(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            mLib.log('EXCEPTION RAISED')
            mLib.log('ARGS:\n'+'\n'.join(str(x) for x in args))
            mLib.log(str(e))
            mLib.log(traceback.format_exc())
    return wrapper
```

It acts correctly in most of situations instead of those when yield is used in a method.

```
class test_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'TEST TEXT'

    @tryexc
    def x(self,a):
        print self.text 
        # yield self.text

    @tryexc
    def y(self,a):
        print list(self.x(5))

test_c = test_class()
test_c.y(5)
```

When the `yield self.text` is commented, everything works fine. The text is printed. But when the line is not commented, it catches an exception.

```
    print list(self.x(5))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I'm not very into decorators so I would appreciate any advice. list(self.x(5)) should be ['TEST TEXT'] in my opinion.

Comment: `wrapper` is not a generator but `func` is, so return it from the try-block: `return func(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets take a simple example to explain your issue -

```
>>> def tryexc(func):
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...         try:
...             func(*args, **kwargs)
...         except Exception as e:
...             print("Hmm", e)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @tryexc
... def a():
...     return "Something"
...
>>> a()
>>>
```

As you can see above, `a` function is supposed to return `'Something'` , but when it got invoked, it did not return anything. Why?

Because when you invoke a decorated function, the wrapper gets invoked first, and then that wrapper invokes the actual function, when the actual function returns something, the wrapper is supposed to return that. But in your case that is not happening. So that is why you are getting `None` when `x()` is called and that is leading to the `NoneType` error.

Now, to fix my case above, I would simple write -

```
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

But in your case, if you just simply do return, what will happen is that it will return the generator object generated when you call `func()` , but if any exception is raised when the actual function is called (when iterating over the generator object) , it will not get caught by your decorator. Example to show that -

```
>>> @tryexc
... def a():
...     for i in range(10):
...             yield i
...     raise Exception('Hmm123')
...
>>> list(a())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in a
Exception: Hmm123
```

This is because once the wrapper returns the generator object, that flow is over and we are no longer inside it. For your generator case, what you really need to do is to create a different decorator , that would yield the results from the generator object returned by `func()`. Example/Demo -

```
def tryexcgenerator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            for i in func(*args, **kwargs):
                yield i
        except Exception as e:
            print("Hmm", e)
    return wrapper
>>> @tryexcgenerator
... def a():
...     for i in range(10):
...             yield i
...     raise Exception('Hmm123')
...
>>> list(a())
Hmm Hmm123
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The above is just an example , you would need to use similar logic for your decorator.